# I cannot get url from a website using nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, scrape

I hope to scrape urls from this website by using the code below:

```
var request = require("request");
cheerio = require("cheerio");
urls = [];

request("http://news.sabay.com.kh/topics/sport", function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode ==200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $(".article","h4.title").each(function(){
            var url = this.attr("href");
            urls.push(url);
        });
        console.log(urls);
    }
});
```

but I cannot get the result. When I run I got this

```
$ node server.js
[]
```

Comment: Please, take a look here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-nodejs-and-jquery--net-22478 . You might find something useful there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use a proper CSS selector :

```
.article h4.title > a
```

Then, use the proper field :

```
var url = this.attribs.href
```

Which gives :

```
var request = require("request");
cheerio = require("cheerio");
urls = [];

request("http://news.sabay.com.kh/topics/sport", function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode ==200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $(".article h4.title > a").each(function(){
            var url = this.attribs.href;
            urls.push(url);
        });
        console.log(urls);
    }
});
```

and outputs :

```
[ 'http://news.sabay.com.kh/article/546826',
  'http://news.sabay.com.kh/article/546763',
  'http://news.sabay.com.kh/article/546520',
  'http://news.sabay.com.kh/article/546568',
  'http://news.sabay.com.kh/article/546460',
  'http://news.sabay.com.kh/article/546448',
  'http://news.sabay.com.kh/article/545674',
  'http://news.sabay.com.kh/article/546235',
  'http://news.sabay.com.kh/article/545698',
  'http://news.sabay.com.kh/article/546091' ]
```